# How do I display the current date and time in a specific format?

Tags: javascript, html, css

On the original Sky EPG, the date and time shows on all pages like this:
[View Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zEXig.png)

I want this to show on my Web EPG, but I'm not sure how to do it. Here's what I've got so far:

```js
function startTime() {
    var today = new Date();
    var day = today.getDay();
    var h = today.getHours();
    var m = today.getMinutes();
    var s = today.getSeconds();
    m = checkTime(m);
    s = checkTime(s);
    day = checkTime(day);
    document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML =
        h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
    var t = setTimeout(startTime, 500);
}
function checkTime(i) {
    if (day = Monday) { Monday = Mon };
    if (day = Tuesday) { Tuesday = Tue };
    if (day = Wednesday) { Wednesday = Wed };

    if (i < 10) { i = "0" + i };  // add zero in front of numbers < 10
    return i;
}
```

This is how it would show on Monday 3rd October at 12:58 for example: 12:58pm Mon 3 Oct

Comment: Would suggest you use [day.js](https://day.js.org/) instead of momentjs. It is much lighter compared to momentjs.

Comment: I saw a comment earlier saying "use Moment.JS" before I saw this, so I went to use Moment.JS and it actually worked: https://imgur.com/a/rX0BNIY

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like that

```
 const date = new Date()
 var days = ['Sun','Mon','Tue','Wed','Thu','Fri','Sat']
 var months = ['Jan', 'Feb','Mar', 'Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec']

const myDate = date.getHours()+':'+date.getMinutes()+' pm '+days[date.getDay()]+'    '+date.getDate()+' '+months[date.getMonth()]
```